SpringToolSuite4 Crashing every now and then on ubuntu 22.04
For past 2 days, I am trying to create very simple spring boot programs. And when I copy some code from other tutorials and put it in the editor and then click on save button then it crashes. I am not able to find any logs where I can see what is going wrong.
This is happening for past 2-3 days. This is also happening when I try to import dependencies and save the files. It was working fine last week. It does not even ask to wait or force quit, it simply crashes and I loose all the work instantly.
Please help me with the next steps.
My system configuration:
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz
RAM: 8 GiB
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I have tried reinstalling STS4. But that did not work. The isue is still there. Within 10-15 seconds of restarting STS4, it crashes.

Now it crashes everytime I open it. No need to edit any files or do anything.

Usually, when the JVM crashes, it creates a crash log file called hs_err_pid.log, probably somewhere within your STS install directory structure. In addition to that it would be also be interesting to see if a plain Eclipse install fails in the same way (just to verify whether this is related to the Eclipse platform or specific to the Spring Tools).

Hard to say what is going on without any crash logs, but maybe this is related to https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1230.
